# Using TestNG @DataProvider in Scala

Tags: unit-testing, scala, testng, scalatest

I am having some trouble getting a test to run that uses TestNg's @DataProvider to supply data to a test written in scala. Here is what i've got so far.

```
import org.testng.annotations._
import org.testng.Assert
import org.scalatest.testng.TestNGSuite
import java.lang.Boolean

class PieceTest extends TestNGSuite {

  @DataProvider(name= "pieceMovesProvider")
  def pieceMovesProvider() = {
    Array[Object]( Array[Object](BISHOP, Position(0,0), Position(1,1), Boolean.TRUE))
  }


  @Test(dataProvider = "pieceMovesProvider")
  def testCanTake(piece: Piece, from: Position, to: Position, result: Boolean) = {
    Assert.assertEquals(result, piece.canTake(from, to))
    //Moves should be commutative
    Assert.assertEquals(result, piece.canTake(to, from))
  }

  @Test def hello() = {
    print(1)
  }
}
```

When i run the test the hello test passes but the other test is skipped with no error or explaination. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the data provider was wrong. It should have been

```
@DataProvider(name= "pieceMovesProvider")
  def pieceMovesProvider() = {
    Array( Array[Object](BISHOP, Position(0,0), Position(1,1), Boolean.TRUE))
  }
```

Comment: Correct, it's Object[][], with each array corresponding to the parameters of your test method

Comment: Is it necessary to even explicitly state that it's an Array[Object] at all? I'm thinking that the inferred type should be okay here.